# Does log4net support zeroconf?

Tags: logging, log4net, zeroconf

I've recently checked out Apache Chainsaw as a viewer for my log4net logs. One feature that struck me as interesting is zeroconf: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/zeroconf/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/ZeroConfSocketHubAppender.html

Does log4net support zeroconf for Apache Chainsaw to consume? Is there a log4net zeroconf appender like the Java ZeroConfSocketHubAppender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and no. But I agree, absolutely interesting.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in more info on log4j and Chainsaw zeroconf support, see this answer:

[Where can I find the source code for log4j's ZeroConfSocketHubAppender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850611/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-log4js-zeroconfsockethubappender)