# Where can I find the source code for log4j's ZeroConfSocketHubAppender?

Tags: log4j, zeroconf, apache-chainsaw

I'm looking for a way to make log4net support zeroconf to publish logs to Apache Chainsaw (see here: [Does log4net support zeroconf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843238/does-log4net-support-zeroconf)). Apparently log4j can already do this using a ZeroConfSocketHubAppender.

Where might I be able to view the source for the java ZeroConfSocketHubAppender? I've looked both in the Apache Chainsaw and in the Log4j repositories but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZeroConf is a log4j 'companion', but ZeroConfSocketHubAppender (and this companion) is no longer necessary due to the fact that most network-based appenders in log4j have ZeroConf support built-in as of log4j 1.2.16.

All you need to do to enable ZeroConf is add jmdns.jar to your classpath and set the 'advertiseViaMulticastDNS' param to 'true' in the appender configuration.

Here's the commit & log info describing the changes which improved ZeroConf support in the appenders (and receivers):
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=924176

Here is a link to the ZeroConf page if you still want to use that 
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/zeroconf/source-repository.html

By the way, the svn HEAD revision of Chainsaw (which should be released soon) includes support for using the advertised ZeroConf appender information to automatically create receivers.

Comment: Here's a blog post from someone who is interested in doing the same thing for log4net (his post is what prompted the improved ZeroConf support in the appenders & Chainsaw).

http://charlesstrahan.com/blog/2010/02/25/logging-troubles/